# GCM XMPP CCS vs MQTT

Tags: android, xmpp, google-cloud-messaging, mqtt, mq

We have a requirement forMachine to Machine communication via our servers.

We initially planned to use MQTT+Rabbit MQ adapter to queue up published messages from clients, process the messages in server and publish it back to other set of subscribers.

With GCM supporting upstream messages via XMPP CCS, the same could be achieved through GCM itself, Since its GCM we dont need to worry about maintaining persistent tcp connection with our servers, and it reduces effort both in server and client side.

Now What are all the design aspects and technology limits should be considered in choosing MQTT with GCM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GCM supports HTTP and XMPP but not MQTT

This article reflects some of the pros/cons on MQTT vs GCM with XMPP
http://ollieparsley.com/2013/05/20/using-mqtt-as-a-gcm-replacement-for-android-push-notifications/

But at the end depending on your specific need you should implement two test clients and see wich one is more efficient on battery usage and message reliability.